# Why did I get 50 points because a question was removed?

Tags: support, reputation, bounties, deleted-questions

I like the reputation points, but... this looks like a bug:

Few minutes ago my reputation increased with *50 points* **because** a question was removed:

> [image]

It was a good voted up question, but closed as too localized, according to Google cache: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8999221/mercury-editors-image-insert-trigger-not-working-in-firefox-in-windows-platform

Is this a bug or a new feature? Any explanation for this?

Also, I don't remember that I had any interaction on that question (like a very downvoted answer or something like that).

Anyway, I would like not to be a bug. :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You gave a bounty of +50 on that question: ([revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8999221/revisions))

> [image]

Soon enough you'll reach 10K and you'll see such questions appear in your [bounty tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1420197/?tab=bounties&sort=offered) as well.

Comment: Hmmm? :-) Good catch, how did you find that?

Comment: @イオニカビザウ He has enough rep to see the deleted question, which there is a link to from the google cache page you gave.  It would also then be visible from your bounties tab.

Comment: I cannot see the revisions, but I still don't see the question in the [offered bounties list](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1420197/?tab=bounties&sort=offered).

Comment: @イオニカビザウ like I wrote, you need 10K.

Comment: @ShadowWizard That's what I said ;)

Comment: @Servy you edited!

Comment: @ShadowWizard Because the question was deleted, can't I see it in the list?

Comment: @イオニカビザウ Because it's deleted and you don't have enough rep to see deleted questions that are not yours, you can't see it in the list.

Comment: Ah, very good. Thank you! I am closer to the 10k milestone. :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Hence the wink.

Comment: @イオニカビザウ cheers, you post excellent answers, expect a pleasant surprise within 48 hours. :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes! Just saw an unexpected upvote to one of my old answers, then I saw why. :-D Thank you! I also will give you a present tomorrow on another site! Thanks! :-)

Comment: @イオニカビザウ cheers! I'm not really active in other sites but will keep my eyes open and any surprise will be welcome! ;-)